# Crawl links and title - storing in a dictionary with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The goal is to crawl links of PDF files and the link title. Everythink should be stored in a dictionary like {"title": "link"}

My code is looking for PDF-File-Links, but the line for the titles isn't working. Only the very last title ist stored and the dictionary is empty. 
Thank for some advise.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/"
r = requests.get(url, verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("pdf")})

#example link
#<a href="Erstellen-Formular2007.pdf" title="Erstellen barrierearmer PDF-Formulare">Erstellen barrierearmer PDF-Formulare</a>

#print(soup)

linklist = []
titlelist = []
pdflist = {}

for link in links:
        crawledlinks = linklist.append(urljoin(url, link.get('href')))
        title = titlelist.append(link.get('title'))
        pdflist[title] = crawledlinks


#print(linklist)
#print(titlelist)
#print(pdflist)
```

Answer (score 1):

The PDF listing is the sixth `ul` on the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/').text, 'html.parser')
new_data = dict([[i.contents[0]['href'], i.contents[-1]] for i in d.find_all('ul')[5].find_all('li')])
```

Output:

```
{
  "Formulare-JLU.pdf": " (21.6.2005/14.7.2005; vermutlich nicht mehr aktuell)",
  "Helpdesk.pdf": " (Februar 2007)",
  "CumTempore-HRZ-Service.pdf": " (Vortrag bei Cum tempore; 24.5.2007)",
  "CumTempore-IT-Beschaffung.pdf": " (Vortrag bei Cum tempore; 24.5.2007)",
  "IT-Beschaffung.pdf": " (Mai 2007)",
  "TdoT-20070621-Geschichte.pdf": " (Tag der offenen T\u00fcr 21.6.2007)",
  "TdoT-20070621-Service.pdf": " (Tag der offenen T\u00fcr 21.6.2007)",
  "Informationsmanagement.pdf": " (3.4.2011)"
}
```

Edit:

If you are attempting to scrape all links:

```
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/').text, 'html.parser')
result = dict([[f"http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/{i.contents[0]['href']}", i.contents[-1]] for i in d.find_all('li') if i.contents[0]['href'].endswith('.pdf')])
```

Output:

```
{'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/antiplagiat.pdf': ' (Mai 2012)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/HS-RheinMain-20140129.pdf': ' (29.1.2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Medienwerkstatt-20140623.pdf': ' (23.6.2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/DFN61-20141015.pdf': ' (15.10.2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Erstellen-Formular2007.pdf': ' (Kurzanleitung für Word 2007, September 2011)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Erstellen-Dokumente-lang2007.pdf': ' (ausführliche Anleitung für Word 2007, Mai 2012)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Erstellen-Dokumente-kurz2007.pdf': ' (Kurzanleitung für Word 2007, April 2012)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/ZKI-Hessen-2012-Vortrag.pdf': ' (21. 11. 2012)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Erstellen-Formular2010.pdf': ' (Kurzanleitung für Word 2010, November 2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Erstellen-Dokumente-lang2010.pdf': ' (ausführliche Anleitung für Word 2010, November 2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Erstellen-Dokumente-kurz2010.pdf': ' (Kurzanleitung für Word 2010, November 2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/vortrag-partosch-DANTE2012.pdf': ' (7.3.2012)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/CiTavi-BibLaTeX.pdf': ' (7.1.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/CiTavi-Word.pdf': ' (29.1.2017)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/http://www.dante.de/events/dante2012/Programm/Vortraege/vortrag-partosch.pdf': ' (Oktober 2002)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/ConTeXt-LaTeX-Tutorium.pdf': <a href="ConTeXt-LaTeX.zip" title="ConTeXt für LaTeX-Umsteiger: Vergleich von LaTeX- und ConTeXt-Strukturen; mit allen notwendigen Dateien">mit allen notwendigen Dateien</a>, 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/context-latex2.pdf': <a href="ConTeXt-LaTeX2.zip" title="ConTeXt für LaTeX-Umsteiger: Vergleich von LaTeX- und ConTeXt-Strukturen; mit allen notwendigen Dateien">mit allen notwendigen Einzeldateien</a>, 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Formulare-JLU.pdf': ' (21.6.2005/14.7.2005; vermutlich nicht mehr aktuell)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Helpdesk.pdf': ' (Februar 2007)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/CumTempore-HRZ-Service.pdf': ' (Vortrag bei Cum tempore; 24.5.2007)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/CumTempore-IT-Beschaffung.pdf': ' (Vortrag bei Cum tempore; 24.5.2007)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/IT-Beschaffung.pdf': ' (Mai 2007)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/TdoT-20070621-Geschichte.pdf': ' (Tag der offenen Tür 21.6.2007)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/TdoT-20070621-Service.pdf': ' (Tag der offenen Tür 21.6.2007)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Informationsmanagement.pdf': ' (3.4.2011)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/PDF-Kurs.pdf': ' (27.10.1999; mit Sicherheit veraltet)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/PDF-Einfuehrung.pdf': ' (Mai 2003)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-Archivierbarkeit.pdf': ' (18.4.2015)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Plone.pdf': ' (interne Weiterbildung Juli 2005)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/pythontex.pdf': <a href="pythontex-beispiele.zip" title="PythonTeX - Zusammenspiel von Python und LaTeX">PythonTeX - Zusammenspiel von Python und LaTeX (Beispiele)</a>, 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/units.pdf': ' (30.8.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/software-lizenzen.pdf': ' (Vortrag bei ZKI Hessen 1.10.2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/spss-verteilung-vortrag.pdf': ' (1.6.2011)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/muenchen.pdf': ' (September 2011)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/ZKI-SL-20140916.pdf': ' (14.9.2014)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-SPSS.pdf': ' (14.4.2015)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/ZKI-SL-20150914.pdf': ' (14.9.2015)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/LaTeX_HTML1.pdf': ' (Vortragsfolien)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/LaTeX_HTML2.pdf': ' (Vortragsfolien)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Gleichzeitiges_Publizieren_in_HTML_und_LaTeX.pdf': ' (25.2.1998, wahrscheinlich total veraltet)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/LaTeX_HTML_Hyperlatex.pdf': ' (Vortragsfolien))', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Hyperlatex-Befehle.pdf': ' (2.10.1997; mit Sicherheit veraltet)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/hyperlatex.pdf': ' (25.2.1998, wahrscheinlich total veraltet)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/LaTeX_und_HTML-Verwandtschaften.pdf': ' (25.2.1998)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/TeX_Internet.pdf': ' (Vortragsfolien, März 1996)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/TeX-im-Internet.pdf': ' (2.10.1999; mit Sicherheit veraltet)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/LaTeX2_Mathematik.pdf': ' (Vortragsfolien, 23. Februar 1999)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Mathe-Beispiele.pdf': ' (30.10.2002)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/XML+TeX-Tutorium.pdf': ' (Oktober 2002)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/LaTeX-Buecher.pdf': ' (27.11.2002; mit Sicherheit nicht mehr aktuell)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/TeX-Einfuehrung.pdf': ' (Mai 2003)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/wissArbeiten.pdf': ' (September 2006)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/textkategorien.pdf': ' (14.9.2006)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Makros.pdf': ' (18.10.2006)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/ams-math.pdf': ' (7.3.2007; überarbeitet 6.1.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Mathe-Beispiele-Wien.pdf': ' (25.2.2009, überarbeitet 6.1.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/BibTeX.pdf': ' (3.3.2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/kriterien.pdf': ' (22.7.2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/BibTeX-Internet1.pdf': ' (25.9.2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/BibTeX-Internet2.pdf': ' (1.4.2011)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-DANTE2014.pdf': <a href="Vortrag-DANTE2014.pdf" title="Anforderungen an wissenschaftliche Abschlussarbeiten">Anforderungen an wissenschaftliche Abschlussarbeiten - Vortrag bei DANTE 2014, 12. 4. 2014</a>, 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-Glossar.pdf': ' (6.1.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Abschlussarbeit-Anleitung.pdf': ' (Version 5.6.1, 28.3.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-Beamer.pdf': ' (7.1.2018', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-Satzspiegel-alles.pdf': ' (5.1.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Vortrag-Ueberschriften-alles.pdf': ' (5.1.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/listen.pdf': <a href="listen-beispiele.zip" title="LaTeX für Abschlussarbeiten - Listen und Aufzählungen">LaTeX für Abschlussarbeiten - Listen und Aufzählungen (Beispiele)</a>, 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/zeilenabstand.pdf': ' (8.4.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/trennungen.pdf': ' (8.4.2018)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/awk.pdf': ' (Februar 1993)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/rechnen.pdf': ' (Juli 1993)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/wintast7.pdf': ' (1996; ist wahrscheinlich nur noch zum Teil gültig)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/dok-layout.pdf': ' (Oktober 2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Word2007_konfigurieren.pdf': ' (Oktober 2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Kochrezept.pdf': ' (10.11.2010)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Word-Dokumentvorlagen.pdf': ' (Juni 2012)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Tasten2010.pdf': ' (Januar 2017)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/Word_konfigurieren.pdf': ' (Januar 2017)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/XML-Kurs.pdf': ' (Ursprünglich: Unterlagen zu einem Tutorium bei der TeX-Tagung DANTE2001 am 28.2.2001 in Rosenheim)', 'http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/unterlagen/XML-Einfuehrung.pdf': ' (Mai 2003; Februar 2004)'}
```

Comment: There are much more PDFs on this site and the titles in your dictionary are wrong. Thank you anyway

Comment: Will it work with similar websites in general? Where can I implement urljoin?

Comment: @Michael It should, as long as the site contains `ul` tags with similar `li` listings. You do not need `urljoin`, instead, just splice the site url and the pdf link. Please see my recent edit.