# Download PDFs from multiple JSON URLs using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, url, export-to-csv

I have been tasked to create a method to download multiple PDFs from URLs included in JSON files. Probably 1 URL per JSON file, with approx 500k JSON files to process in any one batch.

Here's a sample of the JSON file:

```
{
  "from": null,
  "id": "sfm_c4kjatol7u8psvqfati0",
  "imb_code": "897714123456789",
  "mail_date": null,
  "mail_type": "usps_first_class",
  "object": "self_mailer",
  "press_proof": "https://lob-assets.com/sid-self_mailers/sfm_c4kjatol7u8psvqfati0.pdf?version=v1&expires=1635274615&signature=AZlb0MSzZPuCjtKFkXRr_OoHzDzEy23UqzmKFWs5bycKCEcIyfe2od58zHzfP1a-iW5d9azFYUT1PnosqKcvBg",
  "size": "11x9_bifold",
  "target_delivery_date": null,
  "to": {
    "address_city": "SAN FRANCISCO",
    "address_country": "UNITED STATES",
    "address_line1": "185 BERRY ST STE 6100",
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": "CA",
    "address_zip": "94107-1741",
    "company": "Name.COM",
    "name": "EMILE ILES"
  }
}
```

The JSON file is converted to CSV and the URL is downloaded.

Here's what I have been trying to use but it is not working.  What am I missing?

```
Import urllib.request, json, requests, os, csvkit


from itertools import islice
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/Users/MyComputer/Desktop/self_mailers")
paths = [i.path for i in islice(os.scandir(path), 100)]
in2csv data.json > data.csv
with open('*.json', 'r') as f:
    urls_dict = json.load(f)

urls_dict = urls_dict[0]
itr = iter(urls_dict)

len(list(itr))
f.write(r.pdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting your JSON to a CSV?
Btw, if you are unsure of where are the urls in the jsons, I would do this:

```
import os
import json
from rethreader import Rethreader
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.request import urlretrieve


def download_pdf(url):
    # use urlparse to find the pdf name
    filename = urlparse(url).path.rsplit('/')[-1]
    urlretrieve(url, filename)


# use multi-threading for faster downloads
downloader = Rethreader(download_pdf).start()


def verify_url(value):
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        # if the value is not a string, it's neither an url
        return False
    try:
        parsed_url = urlparse(value)
    except AttributeError:
        # value cannot be parsed as url
        return False
    if not (parsed_url.scheme and parsed_url.netloc and parsed_url.path):
        # value cannot be an url because it does not have the right scheme
        return False
    return True


def parse_data(data):
    for value in data.values():
        if verify_url(value):
            downloader.add(value)


for file in os.listdir():
    with open(file) as fp:
        try:
            json_data = json.load(fp)
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
            # this file is not a json; let's skip to the next one
            continue
        parse_data(json_data)
        
# quit the downloader after downloading the files
downloader.quit()
```

If you know in what possible keys can be the urls, I would do as this:

```
# The other parts same as before
def parse_data(data):
    for key in ['possible_key', 'another_possible_key']:
        if key in data and verify_url(data[key]):
            downloader.add(data[key])
```

Comment: Maybe this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134705/crawl-links-and-title-storing-in-a-dictionary-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: @Remmar00 The JSON goes to CSV to supply another software that requires it.  Has nothing to do with getting the PDF.  Thanks!

Comment: Tossed this in my IDE and it tells me the code is not connedcted to the variables